# JavaScript CSV validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to check for comma separated values in  a text box and raise an alert if not found?
And if there is it should be characters in it like `A,B,C,D`

```
  function validate()
   {
         //validate text box;
   }
  <input type="text" id="val" >A,B,C,D</input>
  <input type="button" id="save" onclick="validate()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you

```
function validate()
{
    val = document.getElementById('val').value;
    val = val.split(',');
    alert(val[0].length);
    for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++)
    {
        if(val[i].length != 1){
            alert("Please check value should be coma seperated at every single characters");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="val" value = 'A,B,C,D' ></input>
<input type="button" id="save" onclick="return validate()">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/^[A-Za-z](?:,[A-Za-z])*$/.test(document.getElementById("val").value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a csv library for validating, one of the good ones out there is http://papaparse.com/

```
var  val = document.getElementById('val').value;
var results = Papa.parse(csvString, config)
var errors = results["errors"]
```