# check uploaded file format on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a web portal where end user will upload a csv file and I will do some manipulation on that file on the server side (python). There is some latency and lag on the server side so I dont want to send the message from server to client regarding the bad format of uploaded file. Is there any way to do heavy lifting on client side may be using js or jquery to check if the uploaded file is "comma" separated or not etc etc?

I know we can do "accept=.csv" in the html so that file extension has csv format but how to do with contents to be sure.

Comment: This should be a good starting point.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513642/javascript-csv-validation

Comment: just parse in JS and see if it's got 2+ rows of same # of cols

Comment: Security tip: Never trust data from the client side. Be sure to also verify the contents of the file is text on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing local files from Javascript is only possible by using the File API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) - by using this you might be able to check the content whether it matches your expectations or not.

Comment: `URL.createObjectURL(file)` is another way, though `FileReader` is probably better for this particular task. just saying that the File API is not the only way to get at or use the data of local files anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some bits of code I used to display a preview image clientside when a file is selected. You should be able to use this as a starting point to do something else with the file data. Determining whether its csv is up to you.

Obvious caveat:
You still have to check server side. Anyone can modify your clientside javascript to pretend a bad file is good.

Another caveat:
I'm pretty sure that you can have escaped comma characters in a valid csv file. I think the escape character might be different across some implementations too...

```
// Fired when the user chooses a file in the OS dialog box
// They will have clicked <input id="fileId" type="file">
document.getElementById('fileId').onchange = function (evt) {
  if(!evt.target.files || evt.target.files.length === 0){
    console.log('No files selected');
    return;
  }
  var uploadTitle = evt2.target.files[0].name;
  var uploadSize = evt2.target.files[0].size;
  var uploadType = evt2.target.files[0].type;

  // To manipulate the file you set a callback for the whole contents:
  var FR = new FileReader();
  // I've only used this readAsDataURL which will encode the file like data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODl...
  // I'm sure there's a similar call for plaintext
  FR.readAsDataURL($('#file')[0].files[0]);
  FR.onload = function(evt2){
    var evtData = {
      filesEvent: evt,
    }
    var uploadData = evt2.result
    console.log(uploadTitle, uploadSize, uploadType, uploadData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, makes sense to do it on server side to be sure. I will use this code to do some sort of check on client side.